# Upgrade edition of GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

So I was wondering since I've already got the standard version of GTA V, if I get the Special Edition of it, will I have to start over for single player and online? Or will my progress stay the same? I really just want the vehicles and weapons that are in the special edition. Any answers are appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Special Edition and Collector's Edition games both come with a special code that is applied to your account. This applies to any PSN/XBL profile that you link with your Rockstar Social Club account. As a result, there will be no change to your progress in GTA Online.

Single Player progress is local to your game console. Unless you change consoles in the process, such as upgrading to the PS4/Xbox One, there won't be any loss of save progress.

For example, I purchased the Special Edition of GTA V on the Xbox 360 on launch day. I quit playing the game after a few months, but got the game with the PS4 Black Friday bundle. After linking my Social Club account, I still have access to all of my Special Edition content.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which was about retaining save progress.

Comment: @Studoku It is implied that since it applies to any profile, there's no correlation with save game progress. Alas, I will clarify that.

Comment: So everything will stay the same then and I'd just have to enter the code?

Comment: Also, since I made the terrible decision of waiting this long to inquire about the special edition DLC, I assume there are no more copies of it. Is there anyway to get the DLC that is legit?